# Convert __m256i register to uint64_t bitmask such that that value at each byte's value is a set bit in the output

Tags: c++, simd, avx, micro-optimization, avx2

Basically I have an `__m256i` variable where each byte represents a position that needs to be set in a `uint64_t`. Note all byte values will be < 64.

I'm at somewhat of a loss for how to do this even remotely efficiently.

One option I was considering is in certain circumstances there are a lot of duplicates between the bytes so something along the lines of:

```
__m256i indexes = foo();

uint64_t result         = 0;
uint32_t aggregate_mask = ~0;
do {
    uint32_t idx = _mm256_extract_epi8(indexes, __tzcnt_u32(aggregate_mask));

    uint32_t idx_mask =
        _mm256_movemask_epi8(_mm256_cmpeq_epi(indexes, _mm256_set1_epi8(idx)));
    aggregate_mask ^= idx_mask;
    result |= ((1UL) << idx);
} while (aggregate_mask);
```

With enough duplicates I believe this could be somewhat efficient but I can't guarantee that there will always be sufficient duplicates to make this faster than just iterating through the bytes and setting sequentially.

My goal is to find something this will ALWAYS be faster than what feels like the worst case:

```
__m256i indexes = foo();
uint8_t index_arr[32];
_mm256_store_si256((__m256i *)index_arr, indexes);

uint64_t result = 0;
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
    result |= ((1UL) << index_arr[i];
}
```

If possible I am looking for a solution that can run on skylake (w.o AVX512). If AVX512 is necessary (I was thinking there might be something semi efficient with grouping then using `_mm256_shldv_epi16`) something is better than nothing :)

This is what I am thinking. Going from epi32:

```
    // 32 bit
    __m256i lo_shifts = _mm256_sllv_epi32(_mm256_set1_epi32(1), indexes);
    __m256i t0 = _mm256_sub_epi32(indexes, _mm256_set1_epi32(1));
    __m256i hi_shifts = _mm256_sllv_epi32(_mm256_set1_epi32(1), t0);
    __m256i lo_shifts_lo = _mm256_shuffle_epi32(lo_shifts, 0x5555);
    __m256i hi_shifts_lo = _mm256_shuffle_epi32(hi_shifts, 0x5555);
    
    __m256i hi_shifts_hi0 = _mm256_slli_epi64(hi_shifts, 32);
    __m256i hi_shifts_hi1 = _mm256_slli_epi64(hi_shifts_lo, 32);
    __m256i all_hi_shifts = _mm256_or_epi64(hi_shifts_hi0, hi_shifts_hi1);
    
    __m256i all_lo_shifts_garbage = _mm256_or_epi64(lo_shifts_lo, lo_shifts);
    __m256i all_lo_shifts = _mm256_and_epi64(all_lo_shifts_garbage, _mm256_set1_epi64(0xffffffff));

    __m256i all_shifts = _mm256_or_epi64(all_lo_shifts, all_hi_shifts);
```

or going from epi64 bit:

```
    // 64 bit
    __m256i indexes0 = _m256_and_epi64(indexes, _mm256_set1_epi64(0xffffffff));
    __m256i indexes1 = _m256_shuffle_epi32(indexes, 0x5555);

    __m256i shifts0 = _m256_sllv_epi64(_mm256_set1_epi64x(1), indexes0);
    __m256i shifts1 = _m256_sllv_epi64(_mm256_set1_epi64x(1), indexes1);

    __m256i all_shifts = _m256_or_epi64(shifts0, shifts1);
```

My guess is from epi64 is faster.

Comment: Are the elements sorted, in case that helps?  Somehow use `pshufb` to replace `i` with `1<<i` in 8-bit chunks, 8 times for 8 widths?  Also, `_mm256_extract_epi8` isn't a real hardware instruction, and `vpextrb` only takes an immediate.  You might as well just write it as one vector store outside the loop + indexing a char array inside because that's the only sane way it can compile, and you want to rule out insane ways.

Comment: Perhaps widen elements to 8x 32-bit elements to handle shift counts 0..31 with 4x `vpsllvd`, OR together, and also counts 32..63 separately?  Then unpack them together with `vpunpckl/hdq` to 64-bit bit, OR together, and do an OR reduction to 1 qword elements.  Or just use 8x `vpsllvq`, each handling 4 index elements.  (`vpmovzxbq` to set up the counts).  Not sure if that beats a partially or fully unrolled `bts` loop with a couple accumulators to hide ALU latency, with an OR at the end.  For either latency or throughput.

Comment: I like the idea with ```vpsllvd```, I was actually packing to ```epi8``` earlier for other logic but that could be an intermediate step.

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps at all to do 32-bit if we have to shift 2 different ways for each element in case it was <32 or >=32.  Probably just widening all the way to 64-bit makes more sense unless there's some way to group idx elements where we *know* some groups of them are all <32 or >=32.  Like if they're sorted.  (Note that x86 SIMD shifts saturate the count, not implicitly masking it, which means the high-half shifts would need a masked or subtracted input, but the low half will come out to zero on its own.  Still the upper half would need work to get right.)

Comment: Made edit with possible approaches.

Answer (score 6):

The key ingredient is `_mm256_sllv_epi64` to shift bits within 64-bit lanes, using runtime-variable shift distances.

The code requires C++/17, only tested in VC++ 2019.

Not sure it’s going to be significantly faster than scalar code though, majority of instructions are 1-cycle latency but it’s too many of them to my taste, VC++ produced about 35 of them on the critical path.

```
// Move a single bit within 64-bit lanes
template<int index>
inline __m256i moveBit( __m256i position )
{
    static_assert( index >= 0 && index < 8 );

    // Extract index-th byte from the operand
    if constexpr( 7 == index )
    {
        // Most significant byte only needs 1 instruction to shift into position
        position = _mm256_srli_epi64( position, 64 - 8 );
    }
    else
    {
        if constexpr( index > 0 )
        {
            // Shift the operand by `index` bytes to the right.
            // On many CPUs, _mm256_srli_si256 is slightly faster than _mm256_srli_epi64
            position = _mm256_srli_si256( position, index );
        }
        const __m256i lowByte = _mm256_set1_epi64x( 0xFF );
        position = _mm256_and_si256( position, lowByte );
    }
    const __m256i one = _mm256_set1_epi64x( 1 );
    return _mm256_sllv_epi64( one, position );
}

inline uint64_t setBitsAvx2( __m256i positions )
{
    // Process each of the 8 bytes within 64-bit lanes
    const __m256i r0 = moveBit<0>( positions );
    const __m256i r1 = moveBit<1>( positions );
    const __m256i r2 = moveBit<2>( positions );
    const __m256i r3 = moveBit<3>( positions );
    const __m256i r4 = moveBit<4>( positions );
    const __m256i r5 = moveBit<5>( positions );
    const __m256i r6 = moveBit<6>( positions );
    const __m256i r7 = moveBit<7>( positions );
    // vpor instruction is very fast with 1 cycle latency,
    // however modern CPUs can issue and dispatch multiple instructions per cycle,
    // it still makes sense to try reducing dependencies.
    const __m256i r01 = _mm256_or_si256( r0, r1 );
    const __m256i r23 = _mm256_or_si256( r2, r3 );
    const __m256i r45 = _mm256_or_si256( r4, r5 );
    const __m256i r67 = _mm256_or_si256( r6, r7 );
    const __m256i r0123 = _mm256_or_si256( r01, r23 );
    const __m256i r4567 = _mm256_or_si256( r45, r67 );
    const __m256i result = _mm256_or_si256( r0123, r4567 );

    // Reduce 4 8-byte values to scalar
    const __m128i res16 = _mm_or_si128( _mm256_castsi256_si128( result ), _mm256_extracti128_si256( result, 1 ) );
    const __m128i res8 = _mm_or_si128( res16, _mm_unpackhi_epi64( res16, res16 ) );
    return (uint64_t)_mm_cvtsi128_si64( res8 );
};

inline uint64_t setBitsScalar( __m256i positions )
{
    alignas( 32 ) std::array<uint8_t, 32> index_arr;
    _mm256_store_si256( ( __m256i * )index_arr.data(), positions );

    uint64_t result = 0;
    for( uint32_t i = 0; i < 32; i++ )
        result |= ( ( 1ull ) << index_arr[ i ] );
    return result;
}

static void testShuffleBits()
{
    const __m128i src16 = _mm_setr_epi8( 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 31 );
    const __m256i src32 = _mm256_setr_m128i( src16, _mm_setzero_si128() );
    printf( "AVX2: %" PRIx64 "\n", setBitsAvx2( src32 ) );
    printf( "Scalar: %" PRIx64 "\n", setBitsScalar( src32 ) );
}
```

Comment: https://quick-bench.com/q/X2GHxuaaPcjCCvk8Yi9UfseL9zw original, this, and andrey's. Almost identical results with GCC

Comment: My answer was incorrect, so don't bother benching it. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Sopel The clang assembly output is interesting in your link. It replaced 6 of my fixed shifts with vpshufb with constant shuffle masks: https://godbolt.org/z/jxsz93 While technically less instructions, I’m not sure it was a good thing to do, it traded a couple of very fast instructions for RAM reference, also the code size is much larger due to these constants. I think I like gcc output better, it did what I asked it to do.

Comment: @Sopel Also thanks for that benchmark, I didn’t expect 3.7x speed up of my version, I thought it gonna be maybe 2-3.